# Is there a way to DRY up this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

All I am trying to do is randomize the order that these functions are run. I know this is something that you can loop, I am just unsure how.

```
randomRadio = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
if (randomRadio === 4) {
    createRadios("d");
    createRadios("c");
    createRadios("b");
    createRadios("a");
} else if (randomRadio === 3) {
    createRadios("c");
    createRadios("a");
    createRadios("b");
    createRadios("d");
} else if (randomRadio === 2) {
    createRadios("a");
    createRadios("b");
    createRadios("c");
    createRadios("d");
} else {
    createRadios("b");
    createRadios("a");
    createRadios("c");
    createRadios("d");
}
```

Comment: There are more than four permutations of ways for these to be called, so what's the purpose of the four picked?  Can it be any permutation, or only these?

Comment: Prolly a better question for codereview.stackexchange than SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be equivalent to your code:

```
var radios = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
randomRadio = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
radios.unshift(radios.splice(randomRadio, 1)[0]);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    createRadios(radios[i]);
```

```js
for (var x= 0; x < 20; ++x) {
  var radios = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
  randomRadio = Math.floor(Math.random() * radios.length);
  radios.unshift(radios.splice(randomRadio, 1)[0]);
  
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(radios) + "\n";
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) removes items from an array and returns the removed items: so `radios.splice(randomRadio, 1)` will return an array containing one random item from the array, and this item will no longer be in the original array.

[`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) will simply add this item back at the beginning of the array.

---

If, on the other hand, you simply want to shuffle the array, see the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/).

Comment: Okay, so you're defining an array, generating a random number based on the array, and then what is line 3 doing?

Comment: @Colton this line will remove a random item from the array (`splice`), and then insert it at the front of the array (`unshift`).

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by putting the possible values in an array, then keep removing a random member of the array (and using it with the function) until the array was empty.

This wont limit it to the permutations you have selected above though, it will use all of them.

```
var radio_to_create = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
while(radio_to_create.length) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * radio_to_create.length);
    createRadios(radio_to_create.splice(index, 1)[0]);
}
```